# Как явно указать расстояние от текста кнопки до ее нижнего края? (Android)

Tags: android, xml, button

Есть кнопки, использующие пользовательский стиль. Расстояние от текста кнопки до ее нижнего края отличается в зависимости от длины текста -- в случае, если текст переносится на вторую и более строку расстояние до края значительно уменьшается. Существует ли способ как-то сделать эти расстояния одинаковыми?

[image: Примеры кнопок]

Кнопки в Layout'e:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_in_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="блабла"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_in_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="блабла2"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    />
```

btn_in_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: попробуйте использовать свойство android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"

Comment: В чем именно у вас находятся эти кнопки?

Comment: @taxqwe изменяйте значение в каждой кнопке android:paddingBottom="2dp"

Comment: и android:includeFontPadding в false

Comment: Причину такого поведения кнопки объяснили здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354592/how-to-make-the-space-from-the-text-of-the-button-to-its-bottom-edge-independent